# CouchDB Clojure client API available?

Tags: api, clojure, documentation, couchdb, clojurescript

Does anyone know of a good CouchDB client API for Clojure. I'm currently using [Clutch](https://github.com/clojure-clutch/clutch) although since it's relatively new there doesn't seem too be much documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clutch is the most mature Clojure couch client as of today.

Some folks have done interesting things [using clojureScript to emit the view functions](https://github.com/clojure-clutch/clutch#cljsviews) using it so you can use "clojure all the way through" without configuring your couch server for clojure views (which always struck me as a bit atypical)

Comment: I ended up just going with Clutch for everything except for the views. I couldn't get ClojureScript to work, although since I saw that you could just upload a straight JSON doc containing all your views defs I didn't have enough motivation to get the ClojureScript views working. The project looks promising though.